# ggplot2: geom_bar with facet-wise proportion and fill argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, facet-grid

I'm trying to plot proportions with `geom_bar()` combining `fill` and `facet_grid`.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- data_frame(val_num = c(rep(1, 60), rep(2, 40), rep(1, 30), rep(2, 70)),
                 val_cat = ifelse(val_num == 1, "cat", "mouse"),
                 val_fill = sample(c("black", "white", "gray"), 200, replace = TRUE), 
                 group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 100))


ggplot(df) + 
  stat_count(mapping = aes(x = val_cat, y = ..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. , sum)[..x..], 
                           fill = val_fill),
             position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
  facet_grid(.~ group)
```

[image]

However, it seems that proportions are calculated for all cats (or all mices) in categories A and B together. In other words, sum of proportions in the first three columns is not 1.

It should be solved with adding `group = group` into the `mapping`. However:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  stat_count(mapping = aes(x = val_cat, y = ..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. , sum)[..x..], 
                           fill = val_fill, group = group),
             position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
  facet_grid(.~ group)
```

[image]
plot ignores `fill` argument (and moreover does not solve the issue). I tried to specify group with different choices including `interaction()` but without any real success.

I would like to solve problem within `ggplot` and I would like to avoid data manipulation before plotting.

Comment: What's the reason for avoiding data manipulation before plotting?

Comment: I agree with @amatsuo_net that calculating the proportions upon grouping by `val_cat` AND `group` and then plotting the results will be easier.  Also the `geom_col` function should do what you need.  As for the grouping variable not working right, it did what it was asked and calculated the proportions based on the grouping variable, which also happens to be your entire facets.

Comment: Another possible solution is to create a new variable that `glue`s or `paste`s together elementwise the values of `val_cat` and `group`.  Then use this new variable as the value to `group` within `stat_count`.

Comment: I'm able to do data manipulation by myself, however I was wondering whether this can be done without preprocessing the data.

Comment: @statstew I'm not able to plot desired output with combination of `val_cat` and `group`, could you please post the code? It seams better than grouping data and calculation of proportions..

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't as easy as I thought because I don't tend to use the `stat_xxx()` functions.  Although you seem persistent in not manipulating the data before hand, here is an approach you can use.

```
grouped.df <- df %>%
  group_by( group, val_fill ) %>%
  count( val_cat ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by( group, val_cat ) %>%
  mutate( prop=n/sum(n) ) %>%
  ungroup()

grouped.df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col( aes(x=val_cat,y=prop,fill=val_fill), position="dodge" ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ group )
```

to produce

[image]

But getting back to your "no data manipulation approach", I think your error is within your `y` variable.  For example, consider the following code and output.

```
df2 %>%
  ggplot() +
  stat_count( aes(x=val_cat,y=..count..,color=val_fill,label=tapply(..count.., ..x.. , sum)[..x..]),
              geom="text" ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ group )
```

[image]

In the plot above, the `y` value is the numerator of your attempted proportion and the `label` value is the denominator of your attempted proportion.  I think all you need to do is mess around some more with your `tapply()` function calls until you have the right combination of `y` and `label`.